# In which operating system does my terminal run?

Tags: linux, macos, shell, terminal, zsh

I want to bind a command to a key-combination in zsh, which is different on OSX and Linux. My current state is

```
if [[ "$(uname)" == "Darwin" ]]; then
  bindkey "^e" some-command # Ctrl+E for OSX
else
  bindkey "^[e" some-command # Alt+E for Linux
fi
```

However, this does not work for ssh connections between those two systems. So actually, I don't want to check in which OS my **shell** runs in, but rather in which OS my **terminal** runs in. Is there a way to get that information?

Please don't focus on the details of the keys used in the binding. That's not relevant at this point :)

Edit:
To make things clearer:

- The terminal is the thingy, you type your commands in, like [Iterm2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITerm2), [Guake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guake) or [Xterm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm)
- The shell is the thingy, that receives and executes the commands like [Bash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), [Zsh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) or [Fish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friendly_interactive_shell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ssh` can send environment variables to the server and does this by default for handful of variables. Although any information on the clients operating system is not part of that default list, it can be extended.

1. You need to set and export a variable that has the needed information. You can go with the output of `uname` or you could just copy `OSTYPE` (You should not use `OSTYPE` directly, as changing it may not be a good idea). So you need something like this in your `~/.zshrc` on both systems (somewhere on top before you need it, of course):

   ```
   export CLIENT_OSTYPE=${CLIENT_OSTYPE:-$OSTYPE}
   ```

   This sets `CLIENT_OSTYPE` to the value of `OSTYPE` if it was previously unset. So if you log in locally, it will be the set to `OSTYPE`. But if you log in with `ssh` it will be set to the `CLIENT_OSTYPE` that was passed along.
2. Now you have to set your SSH Clients to actually pass `CLIENT_OSTYPE` to the server. For that you need to edit the `SendEnv` entry ssh client configuration - either user specific (`~/.ssh/config`) or globally (Most likely `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` on Linux, `/etc/ssh_config` on Mac):

   ```
   SendEnv CLIENT_OSTYPE
   ```

   It may already be set to some value in the global configuration (`LANG LC_*` in my case), in that case just add to the list:

   ```
   SendEnv LANG LC_* CLIENT_OSTYPE
   ```
3. Finally, you have to configure the SSH servers to actually accept this environment variable. This can be done in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` on Linux and `/etc/sshd_config` on Mac by modifying `AcceptEnv`:

   ```
   AcceptEnv CLIENT_OSTYPE
   ```

   Similar to `SendEnv` this may also already be set to something:

   ```
   AcceptEnv LANG LC_* CLIENT_OSTYPE
   ```

You then can use the value of `CLIENT_OSTYPE` to decide which configuration you want to use.

Answer (score -1):

I'm thinking that the shell command [`arch`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/arch.1.html) might help you out here.

It will also tell you whether you are on a 32-bit or a 64-bit MacOS machine.

Comment: `arch` only shows information on the system that the **shell** runs in. Also, it is only available on OSX (which would be a solution to the problem, if it could be called from the linux system - but it can't).

Comment: fwiw, ["`arch`" exists on the Linux versions I use](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/man_page).

Comment: Oh, then I didn't see the right package in the AUR search results. At least it's not available by default on my ArchLinux machine.

Comment: ugh... the fact that Arch is the name of the flavor of Linux makes Googling the open source code to compile an `arch` command really tough.